# Tensorflow: Datainput for convolutional network

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, input, deep-learning

I have an "image" with data as:

points: x, y   columns

features: red, green, blue, weight(for pixel)  columns, corresponding to each point

They are saved as tensors with 100 length in each column and i got about 1000 of these rows in
total.
I dont really understand how the input works so i can test a basic convolutional network like one shown in tensorflow example:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/cnn

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons to put input into a model, training and inference(prediction).
For training, you should `compile` and `fit` model.

There are few ways to load images.
You can load one image at a time or load multiple images in batch.
If you want to load images from directory, you should you `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory`

```
data_file = 'image_file_path'

img = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(
    data_file, target_size=(img_height, img_width)
)
img_array = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0) # Create a batch

predictions = model.predict(img_array)
score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])
```

```
data_dir = 'image_dir_path'

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  seed=0,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)
```

reference: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images

Comment: Thanks, but this does not really answer my question on how to use the data I mentioned as input.

Answer (score 0):

Below are three examples you can read through and play around with/debug and hack at to get hands-on experience with in a notebook or IDE.

**1. Generates a tf.data.Dataset from image files in a directory**

```
tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory, labels='inferred', label_mode='int', class_names=None,
    color_mode='rgb', batch_size=32, image_size=(256, 256), shuffle=True, seed=None,
    validation_split=None, subset=None, interpolation='bilinear', follow_links=False
)
```

---

**2. TensorFlow 2.0 - Load Images to tensorflow**

```
import pathlib
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file(origin='https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz',fname='flower_photos', untar=True)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)
```

- pathlib is a module that offers classes representing filesystem paths with semantics appropriate for different operating systems. (from docs.python.org) directory
- We will use `tf.keras.utils.get_file` to download a file named `fname='flower_photos'`. Recap) `train_file_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file("train.csv", TRAIN_DATA_URL)` from load csv post.
- Now, we want to see the explicit filesystem path using pathlib.Path
  then, data_dir will output PosixPath(‘/root/.keras/datasets/flower_photos’).
- Our flower_photos file will be in directory ‘.keras/datasets’
  FYI).keras is something invisible to us but then exists.

**Load using tf.data.Dataset**

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df.values, target.values)) 
### Or...
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_examples, 
train_labels))


BATCH_SIZE = 32
IMG_HEIGHT = 224
IMG_WIDTH = 224
```

**Create a dataset regarding the file paths.**

```
list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(data_dir/'*/*'))
```

For understanding, let’s see how does ‘list_ds’ look like.

```
for f in list_ds.take(1):
  print(f)
```

1. str(data_dir/’*/*’) ‘stringlizes’ the (data_dir /‘*/*’);
   /root/.keras/datasets/flower_photos/*/*.
   The first asterisk is a blank for the class name or the sub-directory then the following is for name of the photo.
2. tf.data.Dataset.list_files(...) will save the strings into tensors.

**Get labels from a file_path: get_label() function:**

```
def get_label(file_path):
  parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, '/')
  return parts[-2] == CLASS_NAMES
```

tf.strings.split spilt the ‘file_path’ taking ‘/’ as delimiter. The pieces or the path components will be saved as a list into ‘parts’

Decode image: decode_img() function.
Decoding is a vague concept, but it is basically a way to convert a human-version of image into a computer-version of image. Our aim with decode_img is to convert an image into a grid format according to its RGB content.

```
def decode_img(img):
  img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3) #color images
  img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32) 
   #convert unit8 tensor to floats in the [0,1]range
  return tf.image.resize(img, [IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT]) 
#resize the image into 224*224
```

Combine get_label() and decode_img() so that we can get (image, label) pair for a given file_path: process_path() function.

```
def process_path(file_path):
  label = get_label(file_path)
  img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
  img = decode_img(img)
  return img, label
There are two lines of code that were not looked into.
def decode_img(img):
img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
```

The line above will convert the compressed string to a 3D unit 8 tensor. This is needed because our process_path function has tf.io.read_file( file_path ) function which reads and outputs the entire contents of the input ‘as a string’

```
def process_path(file_path):
img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
```

**Create a dataset of (image, label) pairs**

We will be using Dataset.map and num_parallel_calls is defined so that multiple images are loaded simultaneously.

```
labeled_ds = list_ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
```

Let’s check what is in labeled_ds.

```
for image, label in labeled_ds.take(1):
  print("Image shape: ", image.numpy().shape)
  print("Label: ", label.numpy())
```

Image shape: (224, 224, 3) Label: [False False False True False]
We resized the image in decode_image() into 224×224. And the 3 is for RGB color image. Label: [False False False True False].Our example is in the Dandelion class.

**Prepare for training**

For efficiency purpose we will be using tf.data api.

```
def prepare_for_training(ds, cache=True, shuffle_buffer_size=1000):
  
  if cache:
    if isinstance(cache, str):
      ds = ds.cache(cache)
    else:
      ds = ds.cache()
  ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=shuffle_buffer_size)
  ds = ds.repeat() #repeat forever
  ds = ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
  ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
  return ds
```

- isinstance(cache,str) function returns true if cache is string type.
- cache saves time (we will be checking this later) because string data is kept in memory and there is no need to load more than once. (in colab environment, it is saved in colab memory).
- Prefetch will prepare your next batch in the background while the model is training.

  train_ds = prepare_for_training(labeled_ds)
  image_batch, label_batch = next(iter(train_ds))
  show_batch(image_batch.numpy(), label_batch.numpy())

**Performance**

We will check performance by measuring time spent in loading images.

```
import time
default_timeit_steps = 1000
def timeit(ds, steps=default_timeit_steps):
  start = time.time()
  it = iter(ds)
  for i in range(steps):
    batch = next(it)
    if i%10 == 0:
      print('.',end='')
  print()
  end = time.time()
  duration = end-start
  print("{} batches: {} s".format(steps, duration))
  print("{:0.5f} Images/s".format(BATCH_SIZE*steps/duration))
```

Compare keras.preprocessing and tf.data

```
#keras.preprocessing - *see example #1 above*
timeit(train_data_gen)
```

1000 batches: 97.74200057983398 s 327.39252 Images/s

```
#tf.data
timeit(train_ds)
```

1000 batches: 16.27811074256897 s 1965.83010 Images/s

The tf.data ‘data generator’ is about 6 times faster with use of .cache it is around 2 times faster

---

**3. Load and Process an Image Dataset**

Read a directory of images on disk

**Setup your code:**

```
import numpy as np
import os
import PIL
import PIL.Image
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
```

**Setup Image Dataset Path**

```
import pathlib
dataset_path = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz"
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file(origin=dataset_path, 
                                   fname='flower_photos', 
                                   untar=True)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)
image_count = len(list(data_dir.glob('*/*.jpg')))
print(image_count)
```

**Each Folder in Dataset Contains Different Classes of Flowers**

```
roses = list(data_dir.glob('roses/*'))
PIL.Image.open(str(roses[0])) # index 0, 1, 2, 3...
```

**Load using `keras.preprocessing` and Create a dataset**

1. Define some parameters for the loader
2. Load these images off disk from directory

Use a validation split when developing your model. We will use 80% of the images for training, and 20% for validation.

```
batch_size = 32
img_height = 180
img_width = 180


train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)


val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)
```

**Print class names of dataset images:**

```
class_names = train_ds.class_names
print(class_names)
```

**Visualize the data & get Tensor Shape**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
for images, labels in train_ds.take(1):
  for i in range(9):
    ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(images[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
    plt.title(class_names[labels[i]])
    plt.axis("off")
```

The image_batch is a tensor of the shape (32, 180, 180, 3). This is a batch of 32 images of shape 180x180x3 (the last dimension referes to color channels RGB). The label_batch is a tensor of the shape (32,), these are corresponding labels to the 32 images.

```
for image_batch, labels_batch in train_ds:
  print(image_batch.shape)
  print(labels_batch.shape)
  break
```

**Data Normalization**

The RGB channel values are in the [0, 255] range. This is not ideal for a neural network; in general you should seek to make your input values small. Here, we will standardize values to be in the [0, 1] by using a Rescaling layer. Or, you can include the layer inside your model definition to simplify deployment. We will use the second approach here.

Note: If you would like to scale pixel values to [-1,1] you can instead write Rescaling(1./127.5, offset=-1)

Note: we previously resized images using the image_size argument of image_dataset_from_directory. If you want to include the resizing logic in your model, you can use the Resizing layer instead.

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers

normalization_layer = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255)
normalized_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))
image_batch, labels_batch = next(iter(normalized_ds))
first_image = image_batch[0]
# Notice the pixels values are now in `[0,1]`.
print(np.min(first_image), np.max(first_image))
```

**Config for Performance**

- .cache() keeps the images in memory after they're loaded off disk
  during the first epoch. This will ensure the dataset does not become
  a bottleneck while training your model. If your dataset is too large
  to fit into memory, you can also use this method to create a
  performant on-disk cache.
- .prefetch() overlaps data preprocessing and model execution while
  training.

  ```
   AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE

   train_ds = train_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
   val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
  ```

**Train the Model**

```
num_classes = 5

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255),
  layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Flatten(),
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(num_classes)
])

model.compile(
  optimizer='adam',
  loss=tf.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
  metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(
  train_ds,
  validation_data=val_ds,
  epochs=3
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not really answer my question on how to use the data I mentioned as input.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean now. Sit tight, I’m about to add a whole bunch of code.

Comment: I am sitting tight

Comment: Ok I set up three examples for you.

Comment: Did you see the answer above I posted?